# Azure Kubernetes Service - Load Balancer now showing

Tags: azure, azure-aks, nginx-ingress

I installed nginx-ingress(Below Command) in AKS service and the public IP is visible in kubernetes service wizard. But unable to access public IP

`kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/controller-v0.46.0/deploy/static/provider/cloud/deploy.yaml`

And when I try to watch out for Load balancer, weird thing is I do not see any load balancer in Load balancer wizard but public IP is shown in Kubernetes service.

It was working few days back and I tried re installing nginx-ingress. Now it is not working as expected. Kind of stuck here and help would be appreciated.

Comment: Any updates on the question? Does it solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you add the namespace when you execute the command to get the details of the services. I show the command here:

```
kubectl get svc --namespace ingress-nginx
```

And if it's the thing you did, then you need to check more things, such as the events that the services showed. Maybe the service is in the pending state or something wrong. You find certain error messages, then you'll also know what you will do.